# The method put <double, double> in the type TreeMap <Double, Double> for the arguments (int, double)

Tags: anylogic

I have the following event2 which contains the following code

```
Incidence += 100000*(nIUScTotal+nIUSeTotal+nIUAcTotal+nIUAeTotal+nIRcTotal+nIReTotal+nIPcTotal+nIPeTotal+nIPcRcTotal+nIPcReTotal+nIPeRcTotal+nIPeReTotal)/TotalPopulation;
//if (Incidence<500000)
//{
IncidenceDS.add(time(), Incidence);
incidences1.put(time(), Incidence);
//Incidence_plot = Incidence;
//}
//traceln(Incidence);
//traceln(nIUSeTotal);
//pauseSimulation();
```

[image]

incidences1 is a collection object of the following type as shown in image,

[image]

When running the code for Monte Carlo Bayesian Experiment the following error shows,
The method put <double, double> in the type TreeMap <Double, Double> for the arguments (int, double)

Previously as mentioned by Mr. Benjamin in the after actions of Monte Carlo Bayesian Calibration Experiment, I put

root.incidences1.put(getCurrentIteration(), root.Incidence_Plot);

Comment: the previous answer was just about the `root` concept, I didn't review the actual purpose :D As Felipe is saying: clarify what you actually want, what you tried and what is not working and we should be able to help :)

Comment: I have created the new question, explaining the next steps. Please check sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are showing is an indication that you don't really know what you are doing... so first take a deep breath, and think very carefully on what you want to achieve...

doing root.incidences1.put(getCurrentIteration(), root.Incidence_Plot); doesn't make much sense and also getCurrentIteration() returns an integer when your map requires a double as the key...

My feeling is that instead you should create another map in your monte carlo experiment... called for example mcIncidences of type Map<Integer,TreeMap>

then you can do `mcIncidences.put(getCurrentIteration(),root.incidences1);`

This code should occur after each iteration

Something like that... I don't know what you really want to achieve so use this as a guide

Comment: Hello Mr. Felipe,

I did as you told. It worked. And now i am looking forward to plotting these values at the end of the experiment run. I wrote the following code After Experiment 

for(Integer iteration: likelihoods_sorted.keySet()){
 double incidence = mcIncidences.get(iteration);
 IncidenceDS100.add(1, incidence);

But it returns the following error,

Type Mismatch: Cannot convert from TreeMap to double

Comment: mcIncidences.get(iteration); returns a tree map, not a double as you are coding it

Comment: i dont know how to plot a chart from treemap. can you show me?

Comment: ask another stackoverflow question